# Columns of Different Height in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I want to create two columns, one column with 3 boxes of smaller height and the second column with 1 box of larger height. However, when I increased the height of the box in the second column, the last two boxes in the first column gets pushed further down the page. I want the 2 columns to happen side by side. (I want the red and blue boxes below to move up next to the large grey box)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="l-board col-xs-12  col-xs-offset-1"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <div class="dashboard col-xs-12  col-xs-offset-1"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="rel-board col-xs-12  col-xs-offset-1"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="exp-board col-xs-12  col-xs-offset-1"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.l-board{
    background-color:#F5FCF4;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
.rel-board{
    background-color:#FAEDED;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
.exp-board{
    background-color: #F0F5FA;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.dashboard{
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
```

Current Look:

[image: Current Webpage]

Layout that I want:

[image: I want the red and blue boxes below to move up next to the large grey box]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bootstrap works based on columns inside of rows. That means it always works horizontally, *then* vertically. To achieve the desired layout, what you'll want to do is consider the page to be comprised of two columns; left and right. The left-most column contains three elements that all take up all of the remaining with (`col-12`), while the right-most column contains a single element with three times as much `height`.

Note that you'll also have to account for any `margin` / `padding` on the right-hand column; in the following, I use a `margin` of `5px` (mostly just to show the `background` for each element), which means that I need to add `20px` of `height` for the right-hand-column (covering the outer `10px` plus the two inner `5px` gaps):

```css
.element {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right .element {
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="element">Top-left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="element">Mid-left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="element">Bottom-left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 right">
    <div class="element">Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This can even be extended using a combination of **[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)** and **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** to ensure that all `height` / `margin` values always map out correctly, so you don't have to worry about handling calculations yourself -- all you have to do is set the base `height` and `margin`:

```css
:root {
  --height: 100px;
  --margin: 5px;
}

.element {
  background: red;
  height: var(--height); /* Each element has the base height */
  margin: var(--margin); /* Each element has the base margin */
  padding: 10px;
}

.right .element {
  /* The right-hand element has [element_count] times as much height 
  and [element_count + 1] times as much margin */
  height: calc((var(--height) * 3) + ((var(--margin) * (3 + 1))));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="element">Top-left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="element">Mid-left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="element">Bottom-left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 right">
    <div class="element">Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```